# Can't Install CentOS 7 - Black Screen

Tags: linux, centos7, supermicro

I'm attempting to install CentOS 7 on a new set of Supermicro Twin2 servers (motherboard model X10DRT-PT).
I've attempted the install via a local USB drive as well as via virtual media mounted through IPMI and through a Raritan KVM.  All have the same result:

After selecting "Install CentOS" at the boot prompt, the system goes to a black screen and stays there.

I'm able to install vmWare, Ubuntu, and Windows on these things without a hitch. What's up with the CentOS install?

Comment: According this document CentOS 7 not compatible with X10DRT-PT http://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/OS/C612_X10_list2.cfm

Comment: Yep, that's one of the first places I looked, but HCLs are always just a bare minimum standard. They don't test every combination and often things not on those lists work just fine. See my answer below for a case to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a CMOS reset, the system was able to install CentOS.
The only thing that appears different between this blade and the others is that there is a setting for expanding the number of interrupts available to the system. On the others, it is enabled. On this one, after reset, it is now disabled and CentOS will install.